# How to raise a Touch event by a Mouse routed event?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, touch-event

I have found the solution of calling the Mouse routed event by code from here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d89862b9-471e-4a3c-a26e-8c9d54e941ea/how-to-support-both-touch-event-and-mouse-event?forum=wpf

```
private void Button_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
  (sender as Button).RaiseEvent(new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, e.Timestamp, MouseButton.Left) { RoutedEvent = Mouse.PreviewMouseDownEvent });
}
```

I want the reverse situation, so it should be something like:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  (sender as Button).RaiseEvent(new TouchEventArgs() { RoutedEvent = Touch.TouchEvent });
}
```

But I don't know what should the three parameters of `TouchEventArgs` be. Also I'm not sure about the `RoutedEvent`. Anybody can help?

Comment: Any reason why you want to raise Touch event on a Button and not a simple Click?

Comment: I want to have the same outcome for both touch and click event.

Comment: from what I know, MouseEvents are raised for Mouse and Touch, in the same way. So if you implement MouseEvents they work for Touch also. At least this is what I do, and it works.